# How to cross-compile Tesseract 3.01 for iOS 5?

Tags: ios5, tesseract

I'm new to cross compiling. I have tried the way from Robert Carlsen's blog [Cross-compiling for iPhone Development](http://robertcarlsen.net/2009/07/15/cross-compiling-for-iphone-dev-884), but I got the error:

**leptonica library missing**

when I tried to compile with `build_fat.sh`.

But I can successfully build Tesseract with `./configure make`.

I’m using Mac OS Lion, XCode 4.3, iOS5.0 SDK.

Does anybody have the updated script for this configuration? It has frustrated me for a few days now…

Comment: Does `build_fat.sh` try to create a fat library, meaning one with support for PPC and Intel?  Or does it mean one with support for Intel and ARM?  Did you build the 'leptonica' library for cross-compilation?  What does `otool` tell you about the libraries - both the Tesseract and the leptonica libraries?  If it says anything different, that may account for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at  [how to: compile and use tesseract (3.01) on ios (sdk 5)](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/).

I tried that a few weeks ago, using Xcode 4.2.x, Mac OS Lion, and iOS5 SDK and **it worked** great. The article provides a list of sources to get (including leptonica) and provides a build script.